# How to call asynchronous function before event.respondWith in Service Worker?

Tags: service-worker

its not work.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
    const url = await localforage.getItem('url'); // url change if page changed
    if(event.request.url === url){
       event.respondWith(handleFetch(event));
    }
});

const handleFetch = async (event) => {
 ....
}
```

if i move url to inside event.responseWith. its work, but do every request, but i need only match url to fetch in service worker if not match then do nothing.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', async (event) => {
    event.respondWith(handleFetch(event));
});

const handleFetch = async (event) => {
  const url = await localforage.getItem('url'); // url change if page changed
  if(event.request.url === url){
    ....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional. Your decision as to whether or not to call `event.respondWith()` needs to be done synchronously, within the top-level execution of your `fetch` handler.

This allows you to do things like examine the request URL and headers synchronously, but it does preclude you from performing asynchronous lookups against things like IndexedDB.

If you can't transition your criteria to use something synchronous, then your best option is to call `event.respondWith()` unconditionally, and when the criteria is *not* met, use `return fetch(event.request)` to come as close as you could to the "default" behavior you'd get if you didn't respond at all. (That's basically what you're doing in the second example.)